# What is the verb for receiving a licence?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, phrase-requests

The verb for granting someone a license (such as a copyright license) seems to be "license", as in "we licensed the software to Foo".

What is the verb for receiving a license?  Also "license"?  As in "we licensed the software from Foo"?

If so, I find the ambiguity of "we licensed the software" irritating, as it does not convey whether we granted or received the license without adding a "to" or "from".

Comment: _We licensed the software from Foo_ works

Comment: I don't see how anyone could flag this as a duplicate to [Can you distinguish the permission to do something from the license, an official document?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184420/can-you-distinguish-the-permission-to-do-something-from-the-license-an-official).  The two questions do not appear to be related to me.

Comment: How not? From accepted answer: _License is not only the document, it is also the permission._

Comment: @mplungjan I was not asking about license as a noun. I'm asking about license as a verb. I'm well aware what license as a noun means. That answer does not help me one bit to learn what verb to use when being a licensee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, we usually use *license* as a phrasal verb, which *[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb)* defines  as

> a verb and a particle and/or a preposition co-occur forming a single semantic unit

When the combination is a verb and preposition, it is often called a *prespositional verb*.

The verb *license* alone can be ambiguous.

> I licensed the software.

Is the subject the grantor or receiver of the license?

Consequently, we can use *license from* to indicate the subject is the receiver (licensee), and *license to* to indicate the subjet is the grantor (licensor).

> I licensed the software from Microsoft.
>
> I licensed my new app to Apple.

**SUPPLEMENT**

There are a number of verbs that describe relationships between parties with different rights where either party can be the subject, the relationship role being clarified with prepositions.  For example

> I *leased* the apartment *to* a nice couple. I know they'll be good tenants.
>
> and
>
> We *leased* the apartment *from* this nice old man. He seems like a great landlord.

Similarly *rented*.

> The driver said, "I *rented* the car *from* Hertz."
>
> and
>
> The counterman told the police he *rented* the car *to* a well-dressed businessman.

Absent the prepositions, the role of the subject is ambiguous.

> I leased the car.

Am I the customer or the rental agency?

Comment: You may be able to present evidence of this as current usage but in my mind it is poor English. I would always use the passive. The software was licensed to me. It is the person granting who licenses; the licensee does not license he/she 'is licensed'. The OED would appear to bear this out. The same poor usage now exists with 'interview'. people talk about interviewing for jobs, when they are the one being interviewed. Corrupted English I call it.

Comment: @WS2 And do you likewise decline tea because water is not permitted to boil?

Comment: @WS2 My experience may be colored by legal usage, but saying someone licensed something from someone is common in my personal experience. The phrase *take a license* is also common.

Comment: @bib Find me an example in the OED of a licensee licensing, and I will agree. Licensees are licensed, licensors license.

Comment: @StoneyB My mum always said the water must be boiling, you should warm the pot and then put in one spoonful of tea for each person,  plus one for the pot. And she did make a nice cup of tea.

Comment: @StoneyB Over every pub doorway in Britain is a plate which states the name of the landlord followed by 'licensed to sell beers, wines and spirits'. If the argument of this post is upheld all these would have to be changed to read 'Nathaniel Naughton licenses the sale of beers etc', which would be nonsense.

Comment: @bib Lots of things in this world are 'common', it doesn't make them right!

Comment: @WS2 English verbs frequently evolve new senses in which the entity previously regarded as the object or Patient assumes the role of subject or Agent, and contrariwise. Doubtless there were those in the 14th century who inveighed against the impropriety of employing *boil* transitively with chickens or eggs as its object, and more in the 15th century who inveighed against the even grosser impropriety of employing it causatively with water or other liquid as its object. Somehow the Language has survived these insults.

Comment: @StoneyB On that basis it seems to me technically impossible for anything which is used to be ungrammatical, which raises questions about the purpose of a site such as this. And it also begs the question as to why public examinations are conducted in such subjects as English Language. Millions use the present participle where they should use the past. But in a GCSE exam (and I've no doubt its US equivalent) it would be marked as incorrect. How would you like your steak cooking, sir?

Comment: @WS2 I don't eat my steak while it's cooking, or drink water while it's boiling. ... One of the purposes of a site like this is to help users distinguish between "rules" which have never been valid (like those requiring genitive subjects for gerunds and prohibiting *wh-* forms in restrictive relatives), rules which were once valid but are so no longer (like that licensing main-verb inversion in questions), rules which are falling into desuetude even in the most formal registers (like that prohibiting permissive *can*) ....

Comment: ... ules which still obtain (like that requiring a single finite verb in every independent clause), rules which are emerging into general acceptance (like dropping periods at the ends of common abbreviations), and rules which have been recently established in the face of bitter opposition (like the use of the passive progressive).

Comment: I have sympathy for using the passive to indicate that the subject is a licensee, not the licensor.  One problem I still have is that often the licensee needs to take action to obtain a license, and I'd like to have an active verb form for that.  If "license" is not it, what is?  Of the proposals I've seen here, "take a license" seems most appropriate, but it doesn't seem to be the applicable in all contexts. What would you use here: "software we have [verb] under an open-source license"? The proposed "license from" doesn't seem to help here, either.

Comment: It's a bit hard. You could simply say *used, utilized, obtained, incorporated,* or *adopted.*

Comment: @altruizine Well the one thing that doesn't fill the gap is 'license'.  As I mention elsewhere on this post the verb 'to license' is really no different to 'to permit'.  And one couldn't say 'Software we have permitted under an open-source permit'. It isn't us who have licensed, or permitted, it is the other party. I would say 'software we have obtained under an open-source licence'.

Comment: @WS2 Actually, you could say *We licensed the software from ABC under GNU [the most common open source license]*.

Comment: @bib But would you say 'We permitted the use of the car from Fred'?

Comment: @WS2 The counterperson would say *I rented the car to that customer*, and I would say *I rented the car from Hertz*.

Comment: @WS2 Please take a look at the supplement above.

Comment: I’m pretty sure indirect objects are allowed for all the *to* cases, like: “I rented him my car for the weekend.”

Answer (score 0):

It's a permit from an authority to **own or use** something.

we **licensed** the software is PERFECT.

i.e, we are **permitted** to use the software.

Comment: But you didn't license it. You were licensed to use it.

Comment: @StoneyB A licence, linguistically, is no different to a permit; and 'to license' no different to 'to permit'. Hence is makes as little sense to say 'I just licensed some software for my computer' as it would be to say 'I just permitted the use of Fred's car for the week-end'. It is the software company which licenses and Fred who permits the use of his car. You are licensed as you are permitted.

Comment: @WS2 I agree that who the agent is appears to be odly reversed if this construction is sanctioned. I think it more normal with licences and such for some rights-holder to **license *people* things** than it is for people to license those same things from the rights-holder.  Otherwise who’s granting the licences to whom becomes confused.

Comment: @tchrist In her 'correct answer' to the previous question on this topic medica states 'Replace license with permission or freedom and that is how the word license can be used'; which is exactly my point. Tis true that people do say 'I licensed the software from XYZ'; but I don't think you would hear the learned justices of the High Court, nor their US colleagues using license quite like that. But I may be wrong.

Comment: No, probably not. I can’t see them using *license* as a verb unless it were in the original sense of sanctioning something, giving someone permission — if then.  The OED says that sense is now rare.